# How do I get 'Reopen windows when logging back in' back?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, reboot

OK, so I have done what it says in *[Disable “Reopen Windows When Logging Back In” in Mac OS X Lion Completely](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-in-mac-os-x-lion-completely/)*, and disabled `Reopen windows when logging back in`, but now I want the feature back. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is given at the end of the article:

> If you ever want to revert back to the default behavior of this OS X Lion feature, just type the following defaults write command:
>
> ```
> sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook
> ```
>
> And you’ll be back to be able to select window restore based on that checkbox’s choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try what was suggested at the bottom of the article:

> If you ever want to revert back to the default behavior of this OS X Lion feature, just type the following defaults write command:
>
> `sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`